# grep a string inside double quotes

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I'm trying to `grep` a path string, everything inside double quotes.
For loop goes through test.txt file, it searches new1.xml for a match. If found, it prints out a string inside of path.

Expected output

```
abc/test/test
abc/test/test
cd/test1/test2
cdf
```

test.txt

```
test/test
test/test
test1/test2
test1
```

new1.xml

```
<abc name="test/test" path="abc/test/test"  />
<abc name="test/test1" path="abc/test/test1"  />
<abc name="test1/test2" path="cd/test1/test2" />
<path="cdf" name="test1" />
```

Script

```
for f in test.txt
    do
    echo "Processing $f"
        paste $f | while read lines; do
            results=`cat new1.xml | grep -o "name.*$lines.*" | grep -o 'path.*' | sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'`
        done
    done
```

output

```
abc/test/test
abc/test/test1
```

Comment: What is the dangling `if` doing in your for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your loop a little more efficiently and use `sed` instead of multiple `grep`s to get what you want:

```
for f in test.txt; do
  echo "Processing $f"
  while read line; do
    grep 'name="'$line'"' new1.xml 
  done < "$f" | sed -E 's/.+path="([^"]+)".+/\1/'
done
```

For your example, the above script gives this output:

```
Processing test.txt
abc/test/test
```

---

If you are just processing one file, you don't need the outer loop:

```
  while read line; do
    grep 'name="'$line'"' new1.xml
  done < "test.txt" | sed -E 's/.+path="([^"]+)".+/\1/'
```

Comment: If you move the pipe to sed to outside of the loop, you call sed just once instead of once for each line.

Comment: You are right @BenjaminW. - just modified the answer.

Comment: thank you very much codeforester and BenjaminW, you both are life saver. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, if you adjust the last part to :

```
....|grep -o 'path=\".*\"' |sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Should work. I didn't test your whole code, only the grep + sed.

Also i can see that there are some backticks around sed command. If so, they need to be removed.

In my test this worked:

```
echo -e "<abc name="test/test" path=\"abc/test/test\"  />" |grep -o 'path=\".*\"' |sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
abc/test/test
```

An alternative way to isolate what you need without a loop but with a single command would be

```
grep -F -f test.txt new1.xml |grep -o 'path=\".*\"' |sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' #or a simpler sed like |sed 's/path=//; s/\"//g'
```

grep -F : search for fixed strings, not regex
     -f : load patterns from file

Another alternative:

```
echo -e "<abc name="test/test" path=\"abc/test/test\"  />" |sed -e 's/^.*path=\"//; s/\" .*$//g'
#in your case:
grep -F -f test.txt new1.xml |sed -e 's/^.*path=\"//; s/\" .*$//'
```

Update: Testing with one-liner:

```
$ cat file3
test/test
test/test
test1/test2
test1

$ cat file4
<abc name="test/test" path="abc/test/test"  />
<abc name="test/testsdk" path="abc/test/testsdk" />
<abc name="test/test" path="abc2/test/test"  />
<abc name="test1/test2" path="ggg/test1/test2"  />
<abc name="test2/test2" path="vvv/test2/test2"  />
<path="cdf" name="test1" />

$ grep -F -f file3 file4 |sed 's/^.*path=//; s/\"//g; s/ .*$//g'
abc/test/test
abc/test/testsdk
abc2/test/test
ggg/test1/test2
cdf
```

Comment: hello @George, if test.txt has duplicate of "test/test" the single command is only printing one result. It is removing duplicates. Is there any way to print duplicates if there are any?

Comment: @Mihir The file test.txt keeps patterns. A duplicate pattern has no meaning. The very first pattern will be used by grep to match all occurences inside xml file. If xml file has different entries but on the same patter , like for example `<abc name="test/test" path="abc2/test/test"  />` , one-liner command will catch those entries also. See tests from my machine in my answer.

Comment: @Mihir Updated again with more xml entries - have a look

Comment: please take a look at my test.txt, new1.xml and expected output. I'm sorry that i wasn't specifix with my question :(. what if path is first in new1.xml which is followed by name="string".

Comment: @Mihir there are new patterns and new xml entries in your revised data. I need time to have a look

Comment: @Mihir See updated tests. Path is caught no matter where it is. About patterns, as i said duplicate patterns have no meaning. With the first pattern test/test all xml entries will be returned.

Comment: please take a look at the expected output - abc/test/test
abc/test/test
ggg/test1/test2
cdf

Comment: @Mihir I also added results of test with while loop. In this case each line of patterns file3 is fed to grep , and grep searches xml file. But with this method grep is invoked a lot of times and the performance will be slow. With a while loop, duplicate patterns will return duplicate results, since grep is called separately for every pattern.

Comment: @Mihir to change output and data all the time is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you George very much, i will try while loop. Again thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: @Mihir For the output you need , the solution of codeforester is more appropriate (i test it) because combines the name part. Try it your self and if it works unaccept my answer and accept codeforester's answer. This is the right thing to be done.

Comment: Yes, i tried codeforester loop and it worked.. Thank you very much for helping